# drawing arrows on curves and shading regions in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw the following figure in my latex using TikZ. I did the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (1,-.3) node[right] {(2,0)}; 
\draw (-1,-.3) node[left] {(-2,0)}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But how can I shade the upper semi-circle and how can I draw the arrows in between?
[image]

**Additional Question**
Thank you so much for your answer. But I have one more doubt: If I use these command in my question I get the diagram right aligned and above the question. But I need it to be beside the question. And sometimes I need to define exactly where I want it to be. What should I do for this?

```
\question Evaluate $\displaystyle\iint_R dxdy,$ where $R$ is the shaded region in the figure.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (1,-.3) node[right] {(2,0)}; 
\draw (-1,-.3) node[left] {(-2,0)}; 
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,0) --(1,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Some body give me the solution for the second question.

Comment: Andd suppose i have two different curves and i need to shade the area between the curve how can i do..

Comment: We appreciate one question per post. If you have another question please post a new one. However, for your first question see my previous comment under my answer. As for second question, what are the two curves? Please add some (full) code.

Comment: $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$@HarishKumar

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps there is a better way, but here is one brute force way. You need to load the `tikzlibraries` `patterns` and `arrows.meta` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (1,-.3) node[right] {(2,0)};
\draw (-1,-.3) node[left] {(-2,0)};
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,-1) --(0,1) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, radius=1cm];
\draw[-{To[length=5pt,width=10pt]}] (0,-1) arc[start angle=-90, end angle=-45, radius=1cm];
\draw[-{To[length=5pt,width=10pt]}] (0,1)  arc[start angle=90, end angle=135, radius=1cm];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly revisit my question. I Have onemore doubt. Thank you for ur help...@darthbith

Comment: If i use these command it is giving this error. {I can't find file 'tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex} give me a solution please. @darthbith

Comment: @David Two things: 1. If you have a new question, please ask a new question instead of asking your new question within this question. 2. You should use the line `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}`. It seems like you are trying to use `\usetikzlibrary{tikzlibraryarrows.meta}` which is incorrect

Comment: sure...@darthbith

Answer (score 4):

This uses decorations and `\clip`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with \arrow{#2}}}]
    \draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw (0,-2) -- (0,2);
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-1) rectangle (1,1);
      \draw[draw=none,pattern=north west lines,pattern color=black!50](0,0)
           circle(1cm);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[postaction={decorate},arrowmark={.375}{>},arrowmark={.875}{>}
    ]  (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \draw (1,-.3) node[right] {(2,0)};
    \draw (-1,-.3) node[left] {(-2,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly revisit my question. I Have onemore doubt. Thank you for ur help...@Harish

Comment: @David Add `baseline={(current bounding box.center)}` to `tikzpicture` options like `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}...]`

Answer (score 1):

Just 4 fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pswedge[fillstyle=vlines,hatchcolor=gray]{3}{-90}{90}
    \psline(0,-5)(0,5)
    \psline(-5,0)(5,0)
    \psset{arrows=->,arrowscale=2}
    \psarc(0,0){3}{-46}{135}
    \psarc(0,0){3}{134}{-45}
    \uput[-90](4,0){$(2,0)$}
    \uput[-90](-4,0){$(-2,0)$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]